# Hello guys I'm trying to creating a get request for generating a OTP request for my application but when I'm running my route it is showing error

Tags: node.js, backend

I'm trying to generate OTP for my application but it is showing a error that Otp is not a constructor

```
Otp is not a constructor at (otplogin\otp\routes\index.js:18:19)
```

Here is my code

```
router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  const number = req.body.number;
  const otp = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
  const otpData = new Otp({
    number: number,
    otp: otp,
  });
  otpData
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "OTP sent successfully",
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: what package are you using to for Otp  ?

Comment: Please mention the packages you're using.